# count for Loop progress React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop

I have a function here that loops through an array of image files, reads the file, and uploads it to aws s3 one file at a time.

Im trying to figure out how to track when the loop is completed and then set a useState variable to true so i can conditionally render certain elements.

I was thinking of creating a counter and when the counter is equal to the array length, call the useState, but I wasn't sure on whats the best way to go about this.

Any direction on this is greatly appreciated.

```
  async function handleSubmit(event) {
         event.preventDefault();

      const filesAsArray = [...fileToUpload.current.files];

        for (let i = 0; i < filesAsArray.length; i++) {                       

      const content = await readContent(filesAsArray[i]);
                      await uploadFile(content);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you just `setState(completed)` after the for loop?

Comment: that's what I thought too

Comment: @forresthopkinsa  I thinks he wants to make sure all promises are resolved wihtout anyone failing

Comment: If he awaits a promise that rejects, it will throw an error and exit the function immediately.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (let i = 0; i < filesAsArray.length; i++) {                       

      const content = await readContent(filesAsArray[i]);
                      await uploadFile(content);
                 if(i===filesArray.length-1){
                     setState(......)
                  }


    }
```

Comment: This does work, and is what I was originally going to do, but I wasn't sure if it was the most efficient way to do it. It seems to work fine for now. Thank you!

Comment: The `if` statement will run only after `resolving two awaits`. In the last iteration, `i===arr.length-1`. And writing `if` after awaits means all iterations are over

Comment: perfect that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score -1):

You can create a promise for the loop and when the loop completes you resolve the promise in this manner you will set completed only when it is actually completed.

```
const loop = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {                       // DO it
      console.log(i)
  };
  resolve('Done');
});

loop.then((successMessage) => {
  console.log("Yay! " + successMessage) 
});
```

Here a small example